# Array of string variables to disable some date in jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an array in javascript like this:

[image]

I tried to disable these dates using datepicker beforeShowday config like this:

```
                     beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', calendar.holidays);
                      return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
                    }
```

but the dates that i want to disable keeps appearing

Answer (score 1):

[the doc](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay):

> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

So our code should: for the `date` passed in, which will be every date that's to be displayed, `jQuery.datepicker.formatDate` it, and check whether the resulting string is one of the `holidays`.

Something like:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
    return [ calendar.holidays.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried to change it, but i got the following error : `Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "datepicker: function(){return true }"
Message: date.getMonth is not a function`